# I am getting different page in httpwebrequest in C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler, httpwebrequest

I am doing a httpwebrequest to recevie a web data from americalapperal.com using this code

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://store.americanapparel.net/en/sports-bra_rsaak301?c=White");
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36";
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        //cli.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return data;
        }
```

I am receiving data from this url

```
http://store.americanapparel.net/en/sports-bra_rsaak301?c=White
```

But this live data is different and the data received my httpwebrequest is different

how could i get exact page data in c#?

Comment: unable to understand the question

Comment: Can run fiddler in the background and see what response you are getting in fiddler when using web browser and when using httpwebrequest?